# LoadLibrary("bthprops.dll") fails, file not found

Tags: winapi, dll, bluetooth

The Microsoft documentation for Bluetooth APIs such as [`BluetoothGetDeviceInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362795.aspx) provide instructions for calling these functions using either static or dynamic imports.

The static import, linking with `bthprops.lib`, works fine.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO binfo = {};
    binfo.dwSize = sizeof binfo;
    binfo.Address.ullLong = 0xBAADDEADF00Dull;
    auto result = ::BluetoothGetDeviceInfo(nullptr, &binfo);
    std::wcout << L"BluetoothGetDeviceInfo returned " << result
               << L"\nand the name is \"" << binfo.szName << "\"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But this isn't ideal in ultra-portable code, because the documentation says they are not supported prior to Windows XP SP2.  So one should use dynamic linking and recover from missing functions.  However, dynamic loading `bthprops.dll` as instructed by the MSDN docs fails:

```
decltype(::BluetoothGetDeviceInfo)* pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo;
bool LoadBthprops( void )
{
    auto dll = ::LoadLibraryW(L"bthprops.dll");
    if (!dll) return false;
    pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo = reinterpret_cast<decltype(pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo)>(::GetProcAddress(dll, "BluetoothGetDeviceInfo"));
    return pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo != nullptr;
}
```

How should one dynamically link to these functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this fact is pretty well known to Google but not to MSDN.  If you want to dynamically load these functions, use `LoadLibrary("bthprops.`**`cpl`**`")` which is the correct DLL name, contrary to the nice table in the function documentation.

This works:

```
decltype(::BluetoothGetDeviceInfo)* pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo;
bool LoadBthprops( void )
{
    auto dll = ::LoadLibraryW(L"bthprops.cpl");
    if (!dll) return false;
    pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo = reinterpret_cast<decltype(pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo)>(::GetProcAddress(dll, "BluetoothGetDeviceInfo"));
    return pfnBluetoothGetDeviceInfo != nullptr;
}
```